# PRISM- PubSubeEvents Library

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-8, microsoft-metro

### PRISM- PubSubeEvents Library

I am developing windows 8 xaml application using prism library.But when I add PubSubeEvents library getting the following error. "**Could not install package 'Prism.PubSubEvents 1.0.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETCore,Version=v4.5', but the package does not contain any assembly references that are compatible with that framework**" How to solve this ??? **Development tool is visual studio express 2012 for windows 8**

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you're using the Prism for Windows Runtime library (http://prismwindowsruntime.codeplex.com/), not the the standard prism library (which targets the full .NET framework, and won't work).

Comment: I have downloaded from the http://prismwindowsruntime.codeplex.com/ but pubsubevent library is not added to the project and getting the same error message. Is it the problem of visual studio express 2012??

Comment: I doubt it.  The pubsubeventlibrary is in the Microsoft.Practices.Prism.PubSubevents.dll, unlike the rest of prism, which is in the Microsoft.Practices.Prism.StoreApps.dll.  Have a look in the file system and see if it's there, and if it is, add the reference manually.  If it's not, grab the [quickstart project](http://prismwindowsruntime.codeplex.com/releases/view/106870) and get the dll from that.